# Remove index.php from url : magento

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I had this requiremnt:

Remove directory `/new /` from the `url: mysite/new/` and the site is built with Magento.

I read all necessary articles over here and over other sites.did all kind of configurations starting from

> 1. Changed the url from admin panel->System->Configuration->Web->Secure and unSecure url.
>
>    Changed Use Web Server Rewrites under Search Engine optimizations from "NO" to "YES". 
>         After i have Reindexed Data -Catalog URL Rewrites - from System-> Index Management.

Added some code in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

as well i tried with

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] (both cases later didnt work)
```

As well I have cleared the Cache and sessions...
I wasnt able to remove that directory + my site was down. I got back the site after i did an undo of my actions. and here i am facing something else: 
My links now have index.php inside the url.

```
mydomain/new/index.php/xxxxxxxxx.html
```

My client used to post on facebook its articles and they have

```
old url : mydomain/new/xxxxxxxxxxxx.html
```

So i have to remove the index.php again. but i cant do that,my site goes down again.

What am i missing over here?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.+)$ http://yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below steps:

1) Enable mod_rewrite apache server.

2) then Go to Admin -> System-> Configuration

Under configuration -> Web -> Search Engine Optimization settings Use Web Server Rewrites->select Yes and save

3) Then Go to Cache management page (system cache management ) and refresh your cache and refresh to check the site.

and also use htaccess as above post.

Comment: nothing changed and after i modified .htaccess file a new problem came out. The website is too slow. takes less than 1 min to open . I overwrited the old .htaccess but still the same. Takes too much time now to reload.I deleted cache and session as well,but nothing good on the way

Comment: website speed is different issue to this.

Comment: what caused the slow performance than? i know it is different issue,but it happened after i did the changes, so the logic takes me at this point.